# Why was GetSystemPowerStatusEx removed from Windows CE 5.0 Standard SDK

Tags: windows-ce

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453172.aspx), GetSystemPowerStatusEx should be available as part of the [CE 5 Standard SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=fa1a3d66-3f61-4ddc-9510-ae450e2318c3&displaylang=en), declared in Winbase.h, as was the case in the CE 4 SDK.  It seems to have been removed, although running an app targetting CE4 does provide the battery status on my device.  Are there any workarounds to this?

My current thinking is to create a small app running in the background that gets the power, writes it to a reg key, and sleeps for awhile to avoid hogging cpu. My main app could then just read the reg key.  This is a it clumsy, and I feel sure there is a better and simpler alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed?  It's there - it's still there [in CE 6.0 too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932748.aspx).  What makes you think it's been removed?

Keep in mind that Windows CE is a modular OS.  It's very possible that an OEM can exclude this call from the OS (likely by removing the Power Manager component - though I've never tried).  That means it's possible that your specific target doesn't have support for the call, but the OS itself certainly still supports it.

Comment: Removed, as in if you download the Windows CE 5.0: Standard Software Development Kit (SDK) from microsoft download centre link given in the question, GetSystemPowerStatusEX is no longered declared in winbase.h, and if you declare it manually you get a symbol not found when you link to the SDK libraries.  This all worked fine in CE 4.0.

Comment: n.b.  I'm not using platform builder, I'm targetting a 3rd party device where the documentation recommends using the Microsoft Standard SDKs.  As i say, this is fine for 4.0, but not so for 5.0

Comment: Ah, the old StandardSDK debacle.  It created way more problems than it ever solved and I've always advised people to never use it.  I'd say that you've got 2 options here.  First is to try to find some other SDK that targets the same processor that does have the definition.  I'd go that route myself, but then I have loads of SDKs from all of the years of CE work.  Another option is to attempt to load it via GetProcAddress.  The main goal is to see if the function really is missing from the OS or if it's just not in your SDK (I'd think that's pretty likely).

Comment: I have a number of SDKs here myself (being hacking away at CE since 1.2), but mostly older.  The 4.0 SDK is fine for my needs, but  doesn't want to integrate with VS2008. What I'm actually trying to achieve is getting a project off eVC++ 4.0 so I can finally stop using it.  I'll probably go with the clunky solution to getting the battery status, as the device in question is also becoming obsolete.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Tried using lib to list all the functions in the 4.0 SDK but its mostly DLL references.  Time to dig out platform builder and have a look for the default implementation, which given it works in the 4.0 Standard SDK is probably just a bunch of IOCTLS anyway.